# Unable to find a system nic while running cloud-init

Tags: networking, cloud-init

I've just encountered a problem while using `cloud-init` to config ubuntu18.04's network.

I can only show you a screenshot from BMC console.

From this screenshot, you could see that `cloud-init` found all MAC addresses including the correct one, but still raised an exception "Unable to find a system NIC ..."

This system is transferred from a qcow2 image file to HDD, and we're using openstack's network_data type as shown in the screenshot.

[image: cloud-init output log]

[image: Network]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by that cloud-init local stage begins too early or network interface recognition is too late. It will be helpful to delay begining of cloud-init local stage.

Cloud-init has five stages during boot sequence.
([cloud-init boot stages](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/boot.html))
And the problem that you encountered is of local stage.

In local stage cloud-init generates network configuration(netplan config file in this case). It must be executed after network interfaces are recognized by OS. Because cloud-init should know the names of interfaces to configure netplan.

I don't know the reason why this kind of situation occurs: Cloud-init local stage begins too early or network interface recognition is too late. I found it out of `/var/log/syslog` and I have solved it by delaying begining of cloud-init local stage.

Cloud-init consists of several systemd services. One for local stage is `cloud-init-local.service` (and is located at `/lib/systemd/system/cloud-init-local.service`.) I run qcow2 image with guestfish and added `ExecStartPre=sleep 30` in `Service` section of `cloud-init-local.service`. ([systemd.service](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html))

In my system, final `cloud-init-local.service` is,

```
[Unit]
Description=Initial cloud-init job (pre-networking)
DefaultDependencies=no
Wants=network-pre.target
After=hv_kvp_daemon.service
After=systemd-remount-fs.service
Before=NetworkManager.service
Before=network-pre.target
Before=shutdown.target
Before=sysinit.target
Conflicts=shutdown.target
RequiresMountsFor=/var/lib/cloud

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStartPre=sleep 30
ExecStart=/usr/bin/cloud-init init --local
RemainAfterExit=yes
TimeoutSec=0

# Output needs to appear in instance console output
StandardOutput=journal+console

[Install]
WantedBy=cloud-init.target
```